# Eager Loading not loading correctlly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Something strange happening when using eager loading.
For example i want the get all authors related with a user, and everyhing was working well, but when i use eager loading it doesnt work well.

Example:

```
Users:
 - id;
 - name
 - ...
Authors:
 - id
 - user_id
 - ...
```

Model User:

```
 public function authorsProfile()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Author::class, 'user_id', 'id');

    }
```

My controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();

//Get all users and the authors that is related with it (Not working well)
dd( $user->with('authorsProfile')->get());

//Get all authors that is related with this user (Working well)
dd( $user->authorsProfile);
```

In my case is supposed to give me only the authors related with the current authenticated user, but for some reason when i try to use eagerloading for some reason is getting all users and there relation (authors)...

Does someone have a idea whats wrong?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `->get()` executes a whole new query that fetches all users.

You are looking for [lazy eager loading:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

```
$user->load('authorsProfile');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the User loaded, using `->with()` is not the correct approach. In your case, try `->load()`:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load("authorsProfile");

dd($user->authorsProfile); // Should be a Collection
```

Technically, you don't even need to call `->load()`, as attempting to access a relationship that wasn't loaded with `->with()` will load it at that point:

```
$user = Auth::user();
dd($user->authorsProfile); // Should also be a Collection
```

To make it work like you have it coded, you'd need to call:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user = User::with(["authorsProfile"])->where("id", "=", $user->id)->first();
dd($user->authorsProfile);
```

But, you can see why that would be inefficient; you'd be calling the database again to retrieve a record you already have.

So, lots of way to accomplish this. See what you can get working.